# Как эффективно составить таблицу сопряженности для категориального признака?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, статистика

Мне на вход приходят данные с 40 категориальными признаками. В данных есть пустые значения. Количество категорий каждого признака не известны. Категории строковые. Задача: посчитать корреляцию с целевой бинарной переменной используя коэффициент V Крамера, который на вход принимает таблицу сопряженности. Я считаю ее следующим образом:

```
# Подсчитанные значения корреляции признаков
categorical_corrs = list()
for column in data.columns:
    # Для каждого признака получаю список уникальных значений,
    # за вычетом пропущенных ячеек
    categories = data[column].dropna().unique()
    confusion_matrix = [[], []]
    for category in categories:
        # Для каждой категории считаем количество реализаций для значений 0 и 1
        confusion_matrix[0].append(
            len(data.loc[(labels[0] == 0) & (data[column] == category), column])
        )
        confusion_matrix[1].append(
            len(data.loc[(labels[0] == 1) & (data[column] == category), column])
        )
    result = cramers_stat(np.array(confusion_matrix))
    # Проверка на исключительные случаи
    if result == -1:
        print column, categories, confusion_matrix
    categorical_corrs.append(result)
```

У каждого признака 40 000 записей (включая пропуски). Выполнение кода выше занимает довольно длительное время. Подскажите, можно ли подсчитать таблицу сопряженности эффективнее?

PS Данные могут быть загружены [отсюда](https://www.kdd.org/kdd-cup/view/kdd-cup-2009/Data) ("small" dataset)

Comment: Можете привести воспроизводимый пример данных?

Comment: @MaxU Я работаю с малым набором данными [KDD Cup 2009](https://www.kdd.org/kdd-cup/view/kdd-cup-2009/Data). Или нужна какая–то подвыборка из нескольких элементов?

Comment: Чему равен `labels[0]`?

Comment: @MaxU Я загружал их [от сюда](https://stepik.org/media/attachments/lesson/90608/_ce5e9e4280a8856218f1886f007de2a4_orange_small_churn_labels.train).

Comment: но там только два значения `-1` и  `1`, а у вас в коде - `0` и `1`?

Comment: @MaxU Я заменил -1 на 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать функцию для расчета коэффициента V Крамера из [данного ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39266194/5741205):

```
import scipy.stats as ss

def cramers_corrected_stat(confusion_matrix):
    """ calculate Cramers V statistic for categorial-categorial association.
        uses correction from Bergsma and Wicher, 
        Journal of the Korean Statistical Society 42 (2013): 323-328
    """
    chi2 = ss.chi2_contingency(confusion_matrix)[0]
    n = confusion_matrix.sum().sum()
    phi2 = chi2/n
    r,k = confusion_matrix.shape
    phi2corr = max(0, phi2 - ((k-1)*(r-1))/(n-1))    
    rcorr = r - ((r-1)**2)/(n-1)
    kcorr = k - ((k-1)**2)/(n-1)
    return np.sqrt(phi2corr / min( (kcorr-1), (rcorr-1)))
```

для расчета `confusion_matrix`, можно использовать функцию [pd.crosstab()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.crosstab.html)

Пример:

```
try:
    from pathlib import Path
except ImportError:
    from pathlib2 import Path

WORK_DIR = Path(r'D:\data\927487')

train = pd.read_csv(WORK_DIR / 'orange_small_train.data', sep='\t')    
labels = pd.read_csv(WORK_DIR / 'orange_small_train_appetency.labels', 
                     header=None, squeeze=True, dtype='int8')
```

---

```
In [51]: confusion_mx = pd.crosstab(labels, train['Var1'])

In [52]: confusion_mx
Out[52]:
Var1  0.0    8.0    16.0   24.0   32.0   40.0   48.0   56.0   64.0   72.0   80.0   120.0  128.0  152.0  360.0  392.0  536.0  680.0
0
-1      371    134     80     46     21      9      6      5      1      3      1      0      2      1      1      1      1      1
 1        9      4      1      0      2      1      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0

In [53]: cramers_corrected_stat(confusion_mx)
Out[53]: 0.20395161570145692
```

PS проверка корреляции категориальных данных - [очень непростой процесс и часто требует хорошего понимания доменных/бизнес данных](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47898377/5741205)

Answer (score 1):

В Python-библиотеке Pandas есть ф-ция crosstab. Она строит нужные вам таблицы сопряженности. Попробуйте, может (и скорее всего, ибо реализация прямая, на С++ ) ее реализация работает быстрее, чем ваша.